# Passing array value to URL shorten method throwing an exception

Tags: google-apps-script, try-catch, url-shortener, google-url-shortener

Am trying to pass array of values to the url shorten method and am getting the shorten form of the url, but the problem is, even though am getting the output, the exception is throwing in the catch block(Exception: Invalid Value). i dont know why it happening. can someone please correct me where am wrong and is this the right way of doing it? 
My code:
    `var lng = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
     try
     {
     for(var i in lng)
     {
    var url = UrlShortener.Url.insert({ longUrl: lng[i]});
    Logger.log(url.id);
    }
    }
    catch(e)
    {
    Logger.log(e);
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are referring to `lng[i]` is wrong. You have take the first value in the single dimensional array `lng[i]` as `lng[i][0]`.

Made some changes to code. Try this

```
function shorturl()
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lng = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  try
     {
       for(var i=0;i<lng.length; i++)
       {
         if(lng[i][0])
         {
           var url = UrlShortener.Url.insert({ longUrl: lng[i][0]});
           Logger.log(url.id);
         }
       }
    }
    catch(e)
    {
      Logger.log(e);
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: @kkr, Its working! thanks for the help. can u explain me little bit more?

Comment: Basically range returns an object where data is stored as a 2-D array like a matrix. For retrieving the values from the range we have to loop through the range. In the first loop we get the first row values of the range object, so 'lng[i]' would be a Single dimentional array even though you have only one value in that row. So for getting the first value we have to access them as 'lng[i][0]'. Hope that explains you everything.